# how to join fetch data from two table with using (like, limit and order by)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table at same database `live_search` and `php_test` .

`live_search` having 4 columns

> > id | name| email | date |

"(some data in name column)"

`php_test` having 2 columns

> > id | name |

"(some data in name column)"

I want to fetch only name value from both table and with use of like , order by and limits.

I m using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name 
FROM live_search 
UNION ALL 
    SELECT DISTINCT name 
    FROM php_test 
    WHERE name LIKE '%$q%' order by name ASC LIMIT 10"
```

Please help me if it is possible

Comment: Using distinct and also union all looks like a mistake. That said you need to apply the where clause to both statements. The order by an limit should automatically apply to both. If that doesn't work for you try an inline view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it like this instead

```
SELECT name from
(
SELECT name FROM live_search 
UNION 
SELECT name FROM php_test 
) tab
WHERE name LIKE '%$q%' order by name ASC LIMIT 10
```